# Python script to light up a led on Raspberry Pi when webpage is viewed?

Tags: python, ubuntu, web, cgi, raspberry-pi

I'm struggling with what i wrote in the subject. The situation is like this:

I have RPi with a lighttpd on address `http://myrpi.com/`
I have another website on address `http://othersite.com/`

In the index of other site (`http:\\othersite.com\index.html`) i want to embed a python script which serves an empty pixel image from the myrpi.com (`<img src="http://myrpi.com/pixel.py">`)

In this script apart from read a png file and printing it's internals back to the requester - I want it to run few shell commands which will light up a led through RPi gpio.

So far I got to this script with the help of others, but it still doesn't work. the serving image part works, the led - doesn't. even though same commands in the command line work fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import time
import cgi
import cgitb


cgitb.enable()

subprocess.check_call(['/home/pi/scripts/wiringPi/gpio/gpio' ,'write', '7', '1'])


print "Content-type: image/jpeg\n"


f=open("/var/www/cgi-bin/1.png")
data=f.read()
f.close()
print data


time.sleep(0.5)

subprocess.check_call(['/home/pi/scripts/wiringPi/gpio/gpio', 'write', '7', '0'])
```

Though, with the `subprocess.check_call` I get an exception (with a normal `subprocess.call` - serves an image but no led): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBSX9.png

A bit lost here. Any ideas how this can be done differently? or how to fix this problem?

Thank you!

**update:**

if i run this in a command line:

`$ sudo /home/pi/scripts/wiringPi/gpio/gpio write 7 1`

it works. without `sudo` - it says:

`/home/pi/scripts/wiringPi/gpio/gpio: Must be root to run. Program should be suid root. This is an error.`

if i suid (`chmod u+s`) gpio then it doesn't work even with sudo.

Comment: What is the expected exit status from `subprocess.check_call`? I mean is non-zero exit status an anomaly or expected?

Comment: Does the webserver process have permissiont to call that script, and then does it also have permissiont write to whatever /dev entry represents that gpio device?

Comment: @MarcB is probably right: you may well get abnormal exit status due to lack of permissions.

Comment: first step in debugging: put the shell code (`gpio write 7 1; sleep 1;  gpio write 7 0`) in a shell script and run it. first as root, then as www-data. make that work.

Comment: I did some investigation and most probably the issue is about what @MarcB is talking.

THis is what I get if I try executing same commands in command line:

`/home/pi/scripts/wiringPi/gpio/gpio: Must be root to run. Program should be suid root. This is an error.`


I tried suid it. `chmod u+x gpio` and also `chmod u+x led.py` = no result.

Comment: what kind of app is gpio? If it's a shell script, you generally can't suid them, because of some nasty race conditions that'd allow a system takeover.

Comment: @MarcB It's python app. installed.

Comment: unless it's a compiled executable, you cannot suid it.

Comment: @MarcB it's built one. https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/download-and-install/